# How to implement ACL in Postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, acl

There are two models in my database: Business and Brand. Each business has one or more access to several brands, such as reading, updating and deleting.

I am not sure what is the best way to implement the access control. For now, I created a joining table with several fields: `business_id`, `brand_id`, `can_read`, `can_update`, `can_delete`, and whenever some action will be taken, I check this table.

However, I realised that such approach is in the application level, not in the database level.

My question is, is there any approach to implement such access control in the database level?

I have Googled "ACL in Postgresql", but the results are all about the accounts of the database itself, not the data it stores.

Please help!

Comment: which version of PG?

Comment: What solution did you come with back then?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider row-level security policies. This is a new feature in PostgreSQL v9.5.

See [Row Security Policies](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ddl-rowsecurity.html) for more information.

Comment: This is for database users. The OP is asking how to model business logic at the SQL level.

Comment: Yes, row-level security policies are defined at the SQL level.  The OP already has a table that defines the rules for each user (can_read, can_update, can_delete), now he needs a way to enforce those rules within the database (as opposed to enforcing the rules within his application logic).

That's what a row-level security policy is for - enforcing the rules within the database.

Comment: you can use row security policies for business logic, just set the user id as a connection parameter and the security function can use this to take a decision

Answer (score -4):

Your starting point should be the [grant](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-grant.html) command in Postgres.
I would usually advice to allow/grant each business just to access a specific view with all his relevant data.
Tables should only be accessible by the admin.

Comment: Maybe I do not express my question clearly. GRANT is to grant PRIVILEGES to database users, but I want to control access of records of the database. After all, I can not create 10000 database users for 10000 business records stored in the database.

Comment: You have one database and one set of a tables. 
Each business has one specific DB user and will have access to its own set of views which are the tables filtered for each business.

Comment: The OP is asking how to model business logic permissions in SQL, not how to limit access to any DB object.